# What's the expression of transformation T in area-based Image operations such as ImageFilter and ImageConvolve?

Tags: image-processing, filtering, convolution

in the “tutorial/ImageProcessing”, as the following picture shows

I just wonder what's the expression of the `T` in the area-based image operations such as `ImageFilter[]` and `ImageConvolve` and etc, because it make me understand why output image looks that more clearly. but i can't find the expression of the `T` even in function-ref-pages such as “ref/ImageConvolve”. is `T` is stable or variable with different `f`?  is it a secret of Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: There is no secret $T$ here, only the function you provide. It is just perhaps a slightly weird notation. ``ImageFilter`` generates an output image pixel-by-pixel. The output pixel value is determined by the function you provide (first argument), to which Mathematica will fed the neighbourhood (with size ``r``) around pixel at the same position in the initial image. So $T$ is just an abstract notation of this transformation which takes a matrix of pixels as input, and outputs a pixel value. Try playing around with different functions, for example:

Comment: ``img = RandomImage[1, {10, 10}, ImageSize -> 200]`` then ``ImageFilter[#[[1, 1]] &, img, 1]`` The input matrix to the function is of size $3\times 3$ (because a neighourhood of size 1 is taken), then the function ouputs the value of the top-left pixel. That is why the ouput image is a simple translation.

Answer (score 0):

1. about ImageFilter[]

Thanks for Domen's answer, the core is the `f` in ImageFilter is a function who eats a Matrix-variable. and for figuring out  what ImageFilter has done, i improve Domen's code as following:

```
img = RandomImage[1, {5, 5}, ImageSize -> 200]
ImageData[img]//MatrixForm
ImageFilter[(Print[MatrixForm@#];Min[#])&, img, 1]
ImageData[%]//MatrixForm
```

part of the output:
[image]

from output we can see:

a) ImageFilter extract sub-matrix whose size is (2r+1,2r+1) and feed it to the `f`

b) at the edge of matrix of `img`, ImageFilter choose value of corner or edge to fill into a same size sub-matrix(3*3 in this case)

2. about ImageConvolve[]

it is just a 2D-discrete convolution, we can use same way(RandomImage,ImageData) to assure its expression.

Comment: This seems like another comment, formatting the result from Domen's comment, rather than an answer.